# Array results using Active Record Query Model 'select' and 'where'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user, membership and group model. A user has many memberships, and groups through memberships. A group has many memberships, and users through memberships. Memberships belongs to both.

When a user accesses the users index view I want to show him/her all users that belong to the group he/she belongs to: I created the following code, which does not work. I cannot seem to get the query to work. Pease help!

The code in the Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
      @users = current_user.relevant_members
  end

end
```

The code in the User model

```
def relevant_members
  group_ids = self.group_ids
  user_ids = Membership.select("user_id").where("group_id IN (#{group_ids.join(", ")})")
  User.find(user_ids)
end
```

I don't understand why, when tested in the console, user_ids is not an array of ids, but the following array:

```
[#<Membership user_id: 2>, #<Membership user_id: 2>, #<Membership user_id: 3>, #<Membership user_id: 3>, #<Membership user_id: 3>, #<Membership user_id: 2>]
```

What would be a better way of returning an array of user ids to find all relevant group members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Membership.select("user_id").where("group_id IN (#{group_ids.join(", ")})")`

returns always an array of Membership objects, select("user_id") changes only the fields that are loaded from DB to the object.

It's enough to map it to id

```
user_ids = Membership.select("user_id").where("group_id IN (#{group_ids.join(", ")})").map(&:user_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Membership.select('user_id')` will return an array of `Membership` objects with just the `user_id` attribute, that's correct so far. It will work if you extract the ids from the result:

```
membershipts = Membership.select("user_id").where("group_id IN (#{group_ids.join(", ")})")
user_ids = memberships.map(&:user_id)
```

Best regards

Tobias

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the pluck() function ?
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

```
user_ids = Membership.pluck("user_id").where("group_id IN (#{group_ids.join(", ")})")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `user_ids` is an object of the class `Membership` and hence you can't get an array of the 'user_ids' directly

You have to do something like following

```
  user_ids = Membership.select("user_id").where("group_id IN (#{group_ids.join(", ")})")
  user_ids_array = user_ids.collect{|u| u.user_id}
  User.find(user_ids_array)
```

Also you can modify your where clause as follow, which is more ruby way.

```
user_ids = Membership.select("user_id").where(["group_id IN (?)", group_ids])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Membership.where("group_id in (#{groups.collect(&:id).join(',')})")
    .all.collect(&:user_id)
```